# sql statemement to select picture

Tags: mysql

hi please see [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/kk/14443265/?f=hp)

in here, u will see **"kk+'s photostream (44,986)" 5 other photos** in thumbnail. and the current photo is selected with a black border.

my website has similar functions that display photo and 5 other photos from the same user. how can i get these 5 other photos using sql statement where the current photo is in the middle??

what i've thought is to get the row number of the current photo. afterwhich, do another sql query that uses limit to find the other 4 photos which is infront and behind of the current photo. but how do i get the row number of a selected row???

**E.g**

We have these photos: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J

If the current photo is C, then the other 5 photos from the same user will be photo A,B,**C**,D,E.

If the current photo is F, then the other 5 photos from the same user will be photo D, E, **F**, G, H

Notice that the current photo is always in the middle of the 5 other photos.
or is there another solution to this??

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you restate what you're looking to do?

Comment: sorry man i 've edited my question..

Comment: basically what i wanna achieve is to get the 5 other photos from the same user. this means that the 5 other photos is dependent on the current photo.

Comment: Rows in database tables aren't ordered, so there's no concept of a "row number" unless you've added it yourself to your schema. Sometimes an ordered primary key can serve that purpose, though, if you can tolerate some failures.

Comment: anw i have included an example to my explanations.

Answer (score 0):

If the current photo has a numerical ID of say `photo_id`, you could use the following SQL to retrieve related photos:

```
SELECT *
FROM   photo_table
WHERE  photo_table.id > (photo_id-2)
   AND photo_table.id < (photo_id+2)
```

If you are not interested in retrieving the current photo, just add a condition to exclude it, i.e.

```
  AND photo_table.id <> photo_id
```

The question is - how to retrieve the id of the selected photo? If you have e.g. the filename of the photo in question, you could query along the following lines:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   photo_table input_photo
WHERE  input_photo.filename = {some_parameter}
LEFT JOIN photo_table other_photos ON 
          other_photos.id > (input_photo.id-2) AND
          other_photos.id < (input_photo.id+2)
```

Hope that helps a little bit.